# can't control-drag UIButton to IBOutletCollection

Tags: ios, uibutton

I control-drag one `UIButton` created a `IBOutletColleciton` and then control-drag the second `UIButton` to the same `IBOutletColleciton`. But there is only `insert...` option. I can't connect the second `UIButton` with the `IBOutletColleciton`.

Could anybody tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: when I change a computer(with a version 6.1 Xcode) the problem solved.... It really puzzled me.  Is the setting of my Xcode(version 6.3.2) something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Create 'outlet connection' when control drag

[image]

then you will see

[image]

now you can connect both buttons to the same connection (drag your button to the label of outlet) works on both obj-c/swift

Comment: my question is I can't control-drag other buttons to the connection. Xcode only shows "insert..."

Comment: are this buttons of the same class?

Comment: I check their class in the Identity inspector. They are all 'UIButton'.

Comment: Did you try to recreate your outlet connection ? i mean remove this property and connect buttons again

Comment: Yes. I tried a lot of times.  Still can't. But when I change a computer(with a version 6.1 Xcode) the problem solved.... It really puzzled me. Is the setting of my Xcode(version 6.3.2) something wrong?

Comment: no, such setting do not exist :) what happens when you try to create a new outlet connection? do you still not able to add objects?

Comment: Yes. I still can't connect objects to the outlet connection. Xcode only show the "insert outlet,action or outletcollection". There is no " connect..." option.